# How can i start an Activity from my sherlock ActionBar Item?

Tags: eclipse, android-activity, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

how can I start any activity from my sherlock ActionBar Item Navigation Menu?
This is my code (i've tried with toast for now and function).

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnNavigationListener  {

private String[] pasti;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    pasti = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Pasti);

    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.Pasti, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);
    getSupportActionBar().setSubtitle("The Subtitle");

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(false);

    getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

   getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);   
}
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
     Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this,"Selected: " + pasti[itemPosition],Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       toast.show();
       return true;
    }

}
```

`
please help. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved with this code:

```
 switch (itemPosition) {
        case 1:
            Intent primi = new Intent();
            primi.setClass(getApplicationContext(), PrimiPiatti.class);
            startActivity(primi);
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
        case 3:
            break;

        }
        // return super.onOptionsItemSelected(itemPosition);
        return true;
    }
};
getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, mOnNavigationListener);
```

}

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```